# Principal Minors of $B[AB]^{-1}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $(n \times m)$ and $(m \times n)$ matrices respectively, with $n<m$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(B)=n$. Consider the matrix $M$ given by

$$ M = B[AB]^{-1}A. $$

I want to prove that all the principal minors of $M$, of order greater than $n$, are equal to zero.

---

It follows from the fact that
$$\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min(\operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B))$$
that the rank of $\operatorname{rank}(M)=n$. So, I think there is just one step missing to prove this, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: If one minor of M, of order bigger then $n$, is not zero then the rank of M is bigger then n. See the section 
"Determinantal rank – size of largest non-vanishing minor"
in this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29

Comment: Thank you, that solves it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: you are welcome